# Two dimensional array in swift (comparing to 1)

Tags: arrays, swift, multidimensional-array, swift2

I am trying to create a Level System for my Breakout game and cant get it done, due to an error that hunts me.

```
let LEVEL_1 : [[Int]] = [
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0],
    [0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0],
    [0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0],
    [0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],]
```

Is the level and then the method

```
   func buildLevel(level: [Int])
{
    let offset:Float = (Float(self.frame.size.width) - (Float(brickWidth) * Float(numberOfBricks) + padding * (Float(numberOfBricks) - 1) ) ) / 2
    var len = level.count

    for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){

        var yOffset:CGFloat{
            switch i {
            case 1:
                return self.frame.size.height * 0.8
            case 2:
                return self.frame.size.height * 0.6
            case 3:
                return self.frame.size.height * 0.4
            default:
                return 0
            }
        }

        for(var j = 0; j < W_LEN; j++){
            if level[i][j] == 1{

                let brick = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "brick")

                let calc1:Float = Float(i) - 0.5
                let calc2:Float = Float(j) - 1

                brick.position = CGPointMake(CGFloat(calc1 * Float(brick.frame.size.width) + calc2 * padding + offset), yOffset)
                self.addChild(brick)
                brick.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: brick.frame.size)
                brick.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
                brick.physicsBody?.friction = 0
                brick.name = brickCategoryName
                brick.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ColliderCategory.brick.rawValue




            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error:  "cannot subscript a value of type int with an index of type int"
appears here: if level[i][j] == 1{

Any Idea how I can solve that error and get my level to work properly?

Comment: maybe you want `func buildLevel(level: [[Int]])`

Answer (score 3):

Look at your code. You are saying:

```
func buildLevel(level: [Int])
```

So `level` is a *one*-dimensional array of Int. Thus it makes no sense to say, later, `level[i][j]`. `level[1]` is an Int, and you cannot say `[j]` (a subscript) after an Int (exactly what the error message tells you).

Comment: Thank you very much matt. Sometimes one focuses too much on the center and forgets the edges. :)